# Creating test run configurations in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am working with an n-tiered architecture in Visual Studio 2008 (Developer Edition), and I have run into an issue.

We are running unit tests on every method of our services layer, and I am attempting to see the code coverage results, to ensure I'm hitting all the main paths through my methods.

When I attempt to view the results, I am informed that the test run did not have code coverage enabled.  I tried editing the test run configuration through test -> edit test run configurations, only to discover that there were none found.

I have yet to discover how to create a test run configuration so that I can enable code coverage results.

How do I create the configuration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right-click the **solution**, choose Add, New item, choose Test run configuration in the resulting dialog.  The only tricky part is that you don't get this choice unless you right-click the solution.

Comment: The only trick is...you need to know the trick.  Thanks!  I'd been clicking on the test project...